# How to make AWS Batch Volume to be persistent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I have two docker containers.First one fetches file from S3 and saves it in a volume and the second one reads and prints the file. To share the files, I am using Docker Volume. 
Now, when I want to run this on AWS Batch, I am defining volume and mount points in job definition. When first container runs, it creates a volume and copies the file. But then, it kills/deletes the volume. So now, the second container is not able to access the file from the same volume.

The AWS Batch documentation says that the volume will persist if we provide source path to volume but it seems to not work.
What is the right way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

At this point of time you can't. The job definition of a batch job can only have one image unlike a ECS task definition where in you can have multiple containers and these containers could share a volume.

Also in the Batch Job the mounted volumes can only be host path based. So basically they can only be paths on EC2 machines in your compute env.

The a few ways I can see what you are trying to do happening is:

a. Create a single container that copies data off of S3 and reads and prints it.

b. Having a compute env that only has a one node, that both the jobs run on. The first job copies data onto a location on the compute env host. And then second job reads off this. This is really not the way to go as you can't potentially scale, and you would have to ensure your job dependencies are setup in the right way to ensure the copying job runs first and then the print job.

c. Use EFS. Basically create a EFS shared location. Then use Launch templates in your Batch Job compute env to specify a user data script that mounts the EFS. And then the first job copies data onto the volume that is backed by the EFS from the host and the second jobs uses the same mount point to read and print. In here as well you would need to setup dependencies clearly.

Another point of consideration, would you have multiple sets of these jobs running that are handling different data. If yes, you need to ensure that in the copy part of it you copy it to a sub-folder that the print job knows about and can read from. Basically a shared id that is used to create a sub folder and then read from as well, example the first job is passed data-id = 1234, so it creates a folder /1234. The same data-id is passed to the second job, and it reads from /1234.

Do note that by default EFS has bursting through put that can be a problem based on your work loads. And if you end you going to route of provisioned through put it might end up being costly.

So all In all if feasible I would recommend #1 as the way to go.

Comment: Amazon has since published a nice tutorial on attaching EFS volumes to Fargate-based AWS Batch job instances here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/hpc/introducing-support-for-per-job-amazon-efs-volumes-in-aws-batch/